# Including css and js files in a JSP not working

Tags: html, jsp, include-path

Hi I am facing a problem including js/css even image src in JSP files.

When my application starts with any context say abc ex. `http://localhost:8080/abc` and browser on a url ex `http://localhost:8080/abc/reports/userCount` and in that JSP i am including css as

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/thirdparty/css/jquery-ui.smoothness.min.css">`

a 404 error is shown in browser console and the URL to download css is formed as

`http://localhost:8080/abc/reports/resources/thirdparty/css/jquery-ui.smoothness.min.css`

But when I am on on a page with URL like

`http://localhost:8080/abc/createBadgeStep2`
 the same include to css works fine because url to download css is created fine.

```
http://localhost:8080/abc/resources/thirdparty/css/jquery-ui.smoothness.min.css
```

I can see clearly here that second slash after Context in the URL is creating problem. But can't figure out how to fix it. The problem goes for js and images too.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Import your stylesheet as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/thirdparty/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
```

If you are importing several resources down the page, better set the context path in a page-scoped variable using the `<c:set>` JSTL tag.

```
<c:set var="ctxPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
```

Then use the variable in your `href` attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${ctxPath}/resources/..." />
```

You would also need to import the JSTL tag library to use the `<c:set>` tag.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: Hi Ravi thanks for your answer. I finally decided to make the static content hosted on a different apache server and so taking a URL for the as a property and using that it in making include urls.
like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cssHostingPath}/resources/..." />`